# Session value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am using PHP and codeigniter. I am trying to set a variable in session.

**Controller**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->config->base_url();  
        $this->load->library('session');
        
        if(!$this->session->has_userdata('zoo'))
        {

        $fooBar = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));//generates random number
        $newdata = array(
                  'username'  => 'nirali',
                  'zoo' => $fooBar
              );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);     
        exit;
        }   
}

public function read_session(){     

        $array =  $this->session->all_userdata();
        print_r($array);
        exit;
}

}
```

On first request constructor's setter method gets executed and it fills session variable. and stops execution because of exit; statement.

And when i call read_session() it prints

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1489646422 [username] => nirali [zoo] => 531d8bfb21ed21b83bc7e3763a04f88c )
```

when I recall read_session() it prints

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1489647898 [username] => nirali [zoo] => cb675bee85da672c95166dbc1dbbdfd2 )
```

I get the value of username to `nirali` which is expected - all good
but for zoo I always get different value, I am expecting same value for the same session

---

**Update**

Upon debugging further I found that. Server is not returning any cookie in response.

[image]

What could be wrong in server configuration which is not sending any session cookie back in response ?

Comment: try $fooBar = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); getting this line out of if statement.

Comment: @Shahid how would that help ? won't it just invoke that with every request (as opposite to setting it once which is what OP is attempting to do)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Not sure. Thats why I suggested in comment and did not post an answer

Comment: Are you destroying session after printing the session ?. otherwise It is always print same value until the session remains if you destroy session then only it print the different values.

Comment: This code is working as expected, might be when you are editing code, you need to regenerate session to confirm your logic. check every time in incognito or reset cookies.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if( ! $this->session->userdata('zoo'))
{
    $fooBar = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));//generates random number
    $newdata = array(
              'username'  => 'nirali',
              'zoo' => $fooBar
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
}
```